# Reading articles from journals or reading articles in journals

Tags: grammar, american-english

Which of the following two sentences is correct grammatically?

1. My interest in physics developed from reading articles **from** scientific journals
2. My interest in physics developed from reading articles **in** scientific journals

Which one is correct??

Please respond...

Comment: ***Grammatically / syntactically***, both prepositions are fine. Idiomatically, ***in*** is far more common for your exact context. But ***from*** would be more common if the articles were "physically separated" from their original "location" within the journals, as in *Professor X emailed me several articles **from** scientific journals for me to read over the weekend*.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification sir.....

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is "both, with different shades of meaning." Besides the "from/in a book" example that FumbleFingers shared, in which "from" suggests reading aloud, it's a little different with journals because you might encounter the article out of context. "Articles *from* journals" might include pdfs emailed by their author or found in a database, whereas "*in* journals" suggests reading *Nature* cover-to-cover. But both associations are so weak that you could use either word for either meaning and still be understood. (You could read from a database and still call them "articles *in* journals," with the understood meaning of "articles [published] in journals," or you could use "from" even if you read the journals straight through.)